# Integration of React App with Java Maven Web Application

Tags: java, reactjs, maven

I am working on an app where I used React for UI Development and Java-Maven based project for backend development. I am trying to integrate both of them so that I will have only one war file to deploy, Is there a way that I could change the output directory of React? At present, it creates a folder called dist and puts all the sources in it. 
I want to change it to webapp directory and run the maven build.

Comment: Why dont you deploy both as separate projects? Will be easy to maintain and develop. Just suggesting

Comment: Never done that before, but yes will definitely consider this option!